# Finding Circular References in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a pre-existing data model where circular dependencies are possible, eg.

`Product -> Bundle -> list of Products -> ...`

This is likely not going to be refactored as it should, so I want to ensure that no circular references exist, so I don't end up in an infinite loop when populating the collection, possibly in the `schema.pre('save')` of the Mongoose model.

Is there a mongodb query that checks for this?  If not, how would I check this?

Comment: What do you mean by circular references in this context? I guess `productX -> (bundleA -> productA) -> (bundleB -> productB) -> ... -> productX`. Is it correct?